# Add style to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't get along with the `link_to` helper and similar stuff. I am trying to add a style to my link but I can't manage to do it, because according to the documentation the parameters are options and html_options, but then some parameters I am using are not even listed in the docs for `link_to` so I don't know which are options and which html_options so I can't rearrage the hashes.

```
<%= link_to '+', :controller => 'shop', :action => 'add', :id => product, :remote => true %>
```

How should I rearrange the hashes to allow me to add `:styles => 'color:red;.....'`?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the paths that are generated by your routes ?

Comment: instead of giving in-line css you can define a class with these properties and then add class to link_to by passing :class => "class_name" in the end

Comment: @AnilMaurya that doesn't work either. The class is going to the url

Comment: <%= link_to '+',  'companies', :id => "product", :remote => true, style: "color: red;"  %> this work . why are you specifically telling the controller action and id

Comment: because it needs to know the controller/action

Comment: <%= link_to "+", add_shop_path(product), class: 'class_name', remote: true %>

Comment: paste the output of `rake routes` from console

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work

```
<%= link_to '+', {:controller => 'shop', :action => 'add', :id => product, :remote => true}, :style=>'color: red;' %>
```

But is there any reason that you're not using the paths generated by the routes?

You can run `rake routes` in your terminal to see paths available to you. Or if you know the controller you're looking for, something like `rake routes | grep shop` will narrow down results for you.

Then you could do something like:

```
<%= link_to '+', add_shop_path(product), :style=>'color: red;' %>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? :)

Comment: I tested it locally in a rails app to make sure, and I was able to get it working: `<a href="/?action=add&controller=shop&id=1" data-remote="true" style="color: red;">+</a>`